# Creating button and labels with short cut

Tags: ios, label

I am new in iOS coding and i am creating labels and button. all the time i have to write same codes for every label and button. is there any way or code to make all buttons and labels in short way??

these are my codes to make 2 label with same code, only name are different.

```
  UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 30,30)];
  [lbl1 setText:@"User Name"];
  lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  [self.view addSubview:lbl1];


  UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 100, 30, 30)];
  [lbl2 setText:@"Age"];
  lbl2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  [self.view addSubview:lbl2];
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html) (this also helps with visualizing). If you stick to generating the user interface via code, you should build a custom method, e.g.

```
- (void)createLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andText:(NSString *)text {
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [lbl setText:text];
    lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
}
```

which you can call repeatedly.

Comment: if i use storyboard the i have to create story borads for iPhone 4, 5 and 6. because frame size is different.

Comment: No, you don't need to; you can use AutoLayout (or the old auto-resizing functionality) to accommodate for different screen sizes. There's tons of information about this on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this code:

```
- (void)addLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andText:(NSString *)text andTag:(int)tagValue {
     UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
     [lbl setText:text];
     [lbl setTag:tagValue]; // To Uniquely Identify you label
     lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
     [self.view addSubview:lbl];
}
```

Call this method like:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfLabel;i++){

    [self addLabelWithFrame:passYourFrameHere andText:@"text to show" andTag:i];
}
```

and to get the label outside the loop try

```
UILabel *lbl = [self.view viewWithTag:passYourTag];
```

UPDATE:

If you put this in AppDelegate then

```
 AppDelegate *refAppDelegate = [[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate]
 [refAppDelegate addLabelWithFrame:yourFrame andText:@"text" andTag:1];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: if i create a singleton class, and declare a method there, and call from my class then will it work?

Comment: It will work but if you want this method global then why don't you add this in AppDelegate.h and .m

Comment: what it will do i am not familiar to this.

AppDelegate *refAppDelegate = [[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate]
 [refAppDelegate addLabelWithFrame:yourFrame andText:@"text" andTag:1];